# EC2 automatically install software

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to automatically install software on all ec2 instances that are created in an account?  This is outside of automation like cloudformation or opsworks.  I know this can be done a number of ways via userdata when launching, etc.

What I want though it to make sure security monitoring agents are always installed on every instance that is launched, even if the instance is just launched through the console.

Is there a way to set a policy like this, or can these be achieved with something like Lambda?

Comment: Put together an AMI with the stuff you want pre-installed, and set up your automation to use that AMI. Or just do it all in the automation.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main ways I know to do this:

- Automation tools such as OpsWorks or CloudFormation, which you've said you don't want to use
- Install via user data script
- Custom a custom AMI. You create an instance, install the required software, then save it as an AMI. All instances are created from this AMI, so you know the required software is installed. I'm not sure if this is setup using IAM or AWS Config.

Comment: I think it is AWS Config rules vs IAM rules to enforce specific AMIs.

Comment: Thanks @JasonMartin, I'll try to find time to check that out, I'll update if I do. I know that you can control access to instance via tags and IAM. eg "user abc can start and stop instances with tag development, but not tag production".

Comment: Yes, at the resource level some api actions can be managed. 
 ec2:ResourceTag/tag-key https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html

Comment: Under "Launching into a VPC using an Amazon EBS-backed AMI" you can specify "arn:aws:ec2:region::image/* (or a specific AMI ID)". If AMI = image that looks like you can restrict users to running specific AMIs/images. It's probably worth the person who asked the question trying it.